# directionsService.route is not going through?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get the Google Maps Javascript API working, and I've copied the tutorial and directions code, but I can't get directionsService.route to work. Here is my code.

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService;
var map;

function initialize() {
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map:map});

    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom:9,
        center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    console.log(google.maps);
    console.log(directionsDisplay);
    console.log(directionsService);
    console.log(directionsService.route);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    function calcRoute() {
        // console.log(map);
        var start = document.getElementById("origin").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("destination").value;
        console.log('start');
        console.log(start);
        console.log('end');
        console.log(end);
        var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        console.log(request);
        console.log(google.maps);
        console.log(google.maps.DirectionsService);
        console.log(directionsDisplay);
        console.log(directionsService);
        console.log(directionsService.route);
        directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
            console.log('hi');
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            }
        });
    };

    $('#origin-search').submit(function() {
        console.log('calling calcRoute');
        calcRoute();
    });
});
```

The console.log('hi') statement is never reached. Attached are the log statements from the console. I first load index, then do the $('#origin-search').submit(), then rerouted back to loading index. Note that the directionsService.route function logs differently inside initialize() than inside calcRoute().

[image: Log Statements]

Comment: What origin/destination are you using? What is the value of `status`, is it not "OK"?  Are you getting any javascript errors in the console? Why are you defining the `calcRoute` function in `$(document).ready`?

Comment: origin and destination are strings, like "new york, ny". I don't know what route is, its never called. No javascript errors. Why not define calcRoute in document.ready?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: What do you expect? when you navigate away from the page and then back the scripts in the previous page are not running anymore.

Comment: I don't navigate back, the page automatically reloads again for some reason.

Comment: Why would directionsService.route log differently in multiple places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I move calcRoute into $(document).ready I get errors because the map isn't initialized yet.  I would call calcRoute only after you are sure the map has been initialized.

Here is some working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Directions Display</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService;
    var map;

    function initMap() {
      directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
      var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: chicago
      });
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map
      });
      calcRoute();
    }

    function calcRoute() {
      var start = "cambridge, ma";
      var end = "boston, ma";
      var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
      });
    };
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to the put the javascript in a separate file and this will still work tho? Or is inline javascript the only way to go?

Comment: @ghui - sure it should make no difference if the script is inline or in a file.  Just use a script tag.  For example `<script src="myjavascript.js"></script>`